# how do i change the iframe content from another iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i want to have an iframe with menus on the left and when clicked i want to change the iframe content on the left. how do I do that?[image]

Comment: A simple way is to use a global variables, a proper way is to use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).